# How to invoke Lambda functions from a separate folder?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using the same functions at various places in my lambda code. Hence I would like to move them to a separate folder to make the code easier to read.

To give you an idea: This is the main function where I would like to invoke the function from (e.g. "showMessage()"):

[image]

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'eu-central-1', apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

const functions = require("functions")

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    //invokes function in separate folder
    functions.showMessage();

}
```

This is the file where I would like to store the functions.

[image]

```
// function in separate folder
function showMessage() {

    console.log("Message from function")

}
```

Hence I would like to know how to correctly set this up and how to correctly invoke the function from the main thread

Comment: Could you please remove those #-#-# ? And add the code right here maybe? I don't want to zoom into screenshots.

Comment: I had to post the screenshots because it's more a question about structure than about coding. I needed to show where I wanted to place / outsource the functions.

Comment: And have you read the [module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) ? If yes, what exactly did not work for you?

Comment: No, `functions/functions.js:` would be enough to show us the files structure

Comment: Dear Jonas, I have posted the code as well. So hopefully this helps to understand my challenge

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by declaring functions as module exports.

```js
/* functions.js */
module.exports = {
  showMessage: function() {
    // code
  },

  anotherOne: function() {
    // code
  }
};
```

```js
/* index.js */
const functions = require('./functions/functions.js');
functions.showMessage();
```